# How to ensure part of the code runs in a single process when using multiple gunicorn workers?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn

I am developing kind of a file-repository system in python that I want to be serving an API endpoint via HTTP.
A main class - the 'engine' - performs read and write operations to disk via appropriate methods `get_data()` and `put_data()`.

The object of the engine class is instanciated in the main entrypoint file containing a Flask app entrypoint with some simple routes

```
repo_instance = VEngine()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    ...
    repo_instance.get_data(params)
    ...

@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST'])
def put_data():
    ...
    repo_instance.put_data(params)
    ...
```

I want to serve the API using Flask with gunicorn using multiple workers:

```
gunicorn -w 4 entrypoint:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Currently, the repo engine instances are obviously multiplied to all 4 worker processes:

```
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (7)
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [40] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 40
[2021-10-07 07:32:14 +0000] [56] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 56
Engine started!
Engine started!
Engine started!
Engine started!
```

When it does spawn multiple workers for handling requests, how to ensure there will always be just one single instance of the engine class (making the app process-safe as it will be the sole process actually performing I/O operations) ?

Comment: *ensure there will always be just one single instance of the engine class* this sound like you need so-called *singleton pattern* implementation (NOT to be confused with *singleton* which is tuple with one element)

Comment: It seems like a good idea - following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) makes me pretty sure about a solution which uses `gunicorn --threads 4` instead of workers and then a Singleton class. That's what I'm going to do for now. However, when using processes, none of the proposed solutions work as the way gunicorn handles it is different from the inner-python multiprocessing. It must be running a separate interpreter for each worker. That is a bit disappointing for me but I probably don't deeply understand it, so the question remains open.